# Supporting set in convex sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, geometry

I am trying to prove that: If $f$ is a continuous linear functional on a compact convex set $C$ then the set $S=\{c \in C : f(c)=\max f(C)\}$ is non empty convex and supporting set in $C$.where $C$ is convex set.

I'm using this definition of supporting set :   $S$ is
called a supporting set in $C$ if S is convex and has the property that if an "inside
point" of a line segment from $C$ belongs to $S$, then the entire line segment must
belong to $S$.That is, if $c_{1},c_{2} \in C$ and $\lambda c_{1} +(1- \lambda)c_{2} \in S $ for some $0 < \lambda < 1$, then both $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ must be in $S$.

Any idea?

Comment: What are the hypothesis on the global space $V$? Does it has a finite dimension? Is it locally convex?

Comment: It's a linear topological space

Answer (score 1):

First note that $S$ is not empty as $f$ is continuous and $C$ is compact.

Further $S$ is convex as $f$ is affine (linear functions can be defined only over vector spaces). To see that let $m = \max_{c \in C} f(c)$ and take $x,y \in S$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$.
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y) = \lambda m + (1-\lambda) m = m.
\end{align*}
Hence $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in S$ and $S$ is convex.

Now we will show that $S$ is supporting. Take $c_1,c_2 \in C$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $\lambda c_1 + (1-\lambda) c_2 \in S$. If $c_1$ or $c_2$ is not in $S$, WLOG $c_1 \notin S$, we have $f(c_1) < m$. But then
\begin{align*}
m = f(\lambda c_1 + (1- \lambda)c_2) = \lambda f(c_1) + (1-\lambda)f(c_2) < \lambda m + (1-\lambda) m = m
\end{align*}
which is absurd.